# Conditionally change url/host header being passed to passenger based app on nginx

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

I have a Sinatra app running with nginx/passenger. In particular occasions I want to change the url Sinatra receives to a mapped variable. I saw passenger_set_header, but it seems to throw an error in a server if block. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with passenger, but it's trivial with other servers, such as unicorn or thin.